# Rails Gem Shopify_app not able to save new products to shop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify

Using the Shopify API and app gem I've created a valid session and activated it, but for some reason I cannot save a new product to the connected Shopify store. See code below

```
session = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(shop,token)
  if session.valid?
     ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(session)
       sellersku.each do |xyz|
         yours = find_by sellersku: xyz
         new_product = ShopifyAPI::Product.new
         new_product.title = yours.title
         new_product.product_type = yours.product_type
         new_product.vendor = yours.vendor
         new_product.body_html = yours.description
         new_product.images = yours.image
         new_product.save

end
```

Comment: If the session is valid like you say the only reason this might fail is because of an empty title. Are you sure all your parameters are present and valid? I just tested it out. `new_product.title = "Test-Product"` and `new_product.save` worked for me and the product was indeed created.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can tell us what exactly the error that you get, also please check your scope, does it include "write_products"?